# How to add a JPanel to a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jbutton

I am creating a minefield game. I need to add two buttons, Clear and Done in their own separate JPanel below the grid and cannot figure out how. Below is the code for the game grid. Thanks!

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MineField extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MineField g = new MineField();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Mine Field");
        frame.add(g);
        frame.setSize(400,400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JButton squares[][];

    public MineField(){
        this.setSize(400,400);
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,5));
        squares = new JButton[5][5];
        buildButtons();
    }

    int [][] num = new int [5][5];

    private void buildButtons(){
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                squares[i][j] = new JButton();
                squares[i][j].setSize(400,400);
                this.add(squares[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

Comment: `JFrame.add(Component c)`

Comment: Use an IDE that has a GUI designer.

Comment: @brifbraff, it is better to learn and understand how layout managers work and design your own GUI that way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default a JFrame uses a BorderLayout.

So currently your MineField class is added to the CENTER of the border layout.

If you want another panel on the frame you can use:

```
JPanel south = new JPanel();
south.add(clearButton);
south.add(doneButton);
frame.add(south, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) for more information and examples to better understand how layout managers work.

Answer (score 0):

We can add components to each other by using the `.add()` method.

Two practical usages of this would be:

```
mainPanel.add(topPanel); //panel to panel
```

or as Quincunx said

```
JFrame.add(Component c); //component to jframe
```

Answer (score 0):

You should modify your code a litte bit, well you can add those few lines :

```
JPanel thePanel = (JPanel)frame.getContentPane(); // this variable will manage the JFrame content

thePanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); // BorderLayout to seperat the Frame on 5 section Center, North, South, Est, West

JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.Right)); // this JPanel made to contain the buttons
btnPanel.add(clearBtn);
btnPanel.add(doneBtn);

thePanel.add(g, BorderLayout.CENTER);
thePanel.add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

hope that helps, Salam

Comment: When ever I try this, it says that I need to make the buttons components. I do and then it doesn't change anything. What should I do about that? Thanks for all the help!

Comment: -1, @user2980816, this answer was given earlier. No need to clutter the forum with duplicate answers. Also, the default layout for a frame is a BorderLayout, so there is no need to get the content pane and create a new BorderLayout.

Comment: thank you for your criticism,  I'll try to be better than that, because I'm new and I didn't know that we can't answer à good answers hère!